# Firebase function log show nothing

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

i just install npm and everything work fine
and deployed my index.js file and i see it in Firebase function
but when i run my app and try to send Notifiction for user i see nothing in the log tab.
in the database cloud firestore i see the message... can someone plz explain it to me? thanks
this is my index.js cose

```
    'use-strict'

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

exports.sendNotification = functions.firestore.document("Users/{user_id}/Notifications/{notification_id}").onWrite((change,context)=> {

const user_id = context.params.user_id;
const notification_id = context.params.notification_id;

return console.log("User ID : " + user_id + " | Notification ID : " + notification_id);




});
```

**edited
i working on a simple app that you can see all the users that registred to the app and then you can choose one of them and send him a message. 
i want the user will get a notification message, this is not a done code but i'm working with a turotial and he shows that when he send a message its write thing in the function log and i dont see that.
[this is my firebase database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3AiaF.png)

[this is my firebase database2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJQPp.png)

[and this is my firestore function look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wqBk.png)

Comment: Please edit your question to explain what exactly you're doing that should trigger the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't `return` the `console.log`, I suspect the calling location either doesn't know how to handle console.log, or is outside the scope and doesn't have access to write to the log.

Try this:

```
'use-strict'

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

exports.sendNotification = functions.firestore.document("Users/{user_id}/Notifications/{notification_id}").onWrite((change,context)=> {

    const user_id = context.params.user_id;
    const notification_id = context.params.notification_id;

    console.log("User ID : " + user_id + " | Notification ID : " + notification_id);

    return;
});
```

EDIT::

Good catch J.Doe! Here is the code returning a promise instead of void...

Also, since you added your DB structure to the question, I noticed your node in FB is singular "*Notification*" where as your trigger uses plural "*Notifications*"

```
exports.sendNotification = functions.firestore.document("Users/{user_id}/Notification/{notification_id}").onWrite((change,context)=> {

    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
        const user_id = context.params.user_id;
        const notification_id = context.params.notification_id;

        console.log("User ID : " + user_id + " | Notification ID : " + notification_id);
        resolve();
    });

});
```

Comment: in the logs tab its still says: "No logs for this project yet" 
in the Dashbord i see my deploy but its also got title at the right as "time out" and below that 60s and next to it "memory" 256MB and "run-time" node.js 6...

Comment: Don't return void, return a promise :)

Comment: man it's worked !! the only problem was that in DB its was Notificaiton and i try to get from Notifications . thanks you for notice that  !